# My program doesn't display the correct calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator, calculation

I'm making a credit score calculator for my class and the only problem I'm having with my code is that none of the calculations are turning out correctly. This is my code for the logic portion

```
def calculate_score():
    name = entry_name.get()
    highschool_checked = int(highschool.get())
    college_checked = int(college.get())
    university_checked = int(university.get())
    income = int(entry_income.get())
    savings = int(entry_savings.get())
  
    para1 = 0

    if int(income) >= 20000:
        para1 = 1
    elif int(income) >= 60000:
        para1 = 2
    elif int(income) >= 90000:
        para1 = 3

    para2 = 1

    if int(highschool_checked) == 1:
        para2 = 1
    elif int(college_checked) == 1:
        para2 = 2
    elif int(university_checked) == 1:
        para2 = 3

    para3 = 0

    if int(savings) >= 5000:
        para3 = 1
    elif int(savings) >= 10000:
        para3 = 2
    elif int(savings) >= 20000:
        para3 = 3

    score = 2*para1 + 3*para2 + para3
    
    if score >= 8:
        result = str(name) + ", your credit score is " + str(score) + ". You are qualified for credit."
    else: result = str(name) + ", your credit score is " + str(score) + ". You are not qualified for credit."
    
    label_result = tkinter.Label(text="")
    label_result.configure(text=result)
    label_result.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

This code is all within a "Calculate Credit Score" button. I've checked for any errors and there are none but whenever I run the program it always gives me the wrong result.

I tried a test case by entering every parameter at the max setting (income = $90000, education = University, savings = $20000) and the expected output is supposed to be a credit score of 18. But when I run the program it gives me a credit score of 12. I even tried in the python shell and it still gave me a credit score of 12.

Comment: " I've checked for any errors and there are none but whenever I run the program it always gives me the wrong result." That sound like a self contradictory statement, doesn't it?

Comment: "the expected output is supposed to be a credit score of 18." We have no way to know what is expected... [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Ask yourself: What would be the value of `para1` when the income is `90000`? Is it `1` or `3`?